# What is the syntax for an area of unspecificed length/characters when using findall in python re?

Tags: python, regex, string, parsing, findall

I am trying to capture protein names and their corresponding amino acid sequence in some data I have using regex. Here's a condensed version of my code:

```
import re
line=">sp|A0A385XJ53|INSA9_ECOLI Insertion element OS=Escherichia coli (strain K12) PE=3 SV=1 MASVSISCPSCSATDGVVRNGKSTAGHQRYLCSHCRKTWQLQFTYTASQPGTHQKIIDMA >sp|A0A385XJE6|INH21_ECOLI Transposase InsH for insertion sequence element OS=Escherichia coli (strain K12) PE=3 SV=1 MFVIWSHRTGFIMSHQLTFADSEFSSKRRQTRKEIFLSRMEQILPWQNMVEVIEPFYPKA >sp|A0A385XJL4|INSB9_ECOLI Insertion element IS1 9 protein OS=Escherichia coli (strain K12) PE=3 SV=2 MPGNSPHYGRWPQHDFTSLKKLRPQSVTSRIQPGSDVIVCAEMDEQWGYVGAKSRQRWLF"

result1=re.findall(r'SV=\d\s([A-Z]+)', line)
result2=re.findall(r'>sp\|(\w+)\|', line)
result3=re.findall(r'>sp\|(\w+)\|\.\SV=\d\s([A-Z]+)', line)
for item1 in result1:
    print(item1)
for item2 in result2:
    print(item2)
for item3 in result3:
    print(item3)
```

Result1 outputs:

```
MASVSISCPSCSATDGVVRNGKSTAGHQRYLCSHCRKTWQLQFTYTASQPGTHQKIIDMA
MFVIWSHRTGFIMSHQLTFADSEFSSKRRQTRKEIFLSRMEQILPWQNMVEVIEPFYPKA
MPGNSPHYGRWPQHDFTSLKKLRPQSVTSRIQPGSDVIVCAEMDEQWGYVGAKSRQRWLF
```

And result2 outputs:

```
A0A385XJ53
A0A385XJE6
A0A385XJL4
```

However, result3 outputs nothing. I was under the impression that "." can be used for a sequence of unspecified characters when using regex. What syntax can be used for a series of unspecified characters without a set length? I essentially want python to look for a match to >sp\|(\w+)\| and continue until it finds SV=\d\s([A-Z]+). At which point, it will reset to looking for >sp\|(\w+)\|'s match. How can I achieve this? I'm wanting it to output something like:

```
A0A385XJ53 MASVSISCPSCSATDGVVRNGKSTAGHQRYLCSHCRKTWQLQFTYTASQPGTHQKIIDMA
A0A385XJE6 MFVIWSHRTGFIMSHQLTFADSEFSSKRRQTRKEIFLSRMEQILPWQNMVEVIEPFYPKA
A0A385XJL4 MPGNSPHYGRWPQHDFTSLKKLRPQSVTSRIQPGSDVIVCAEMDEQWGYVGAKSRQRWLF
```

I've played around with a couple of different things thinking that maybe I'm not understanding the use of ".". Since my code has converted all the proteins to a single string, I figured I could use "\b+" or "\b*" in its place since there are no new lines. I get the following error code for both.

```
error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-76-f43b57fdde31> in <module>()
      8 result1=re.findall(r'SV=\d\s([A-Z]+)', line)
      9 result2=re.findall(r'>sp\|(\w+)\|', line)
---> 10 result3=re.findall(r'>sp\|(\w+)\|\b*\SV=\d\s([A-Z]+)', line)
     11 for item1 in result1:
     12     print(item1)

~\OneDrive\Documents\Python stuff\Pythonstuff\lib\re.py in findall(pattern, string, flags)
    220 
    221     Empty matches are included in the result."""
--> 222     return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)
    223 
    224 def finditer(pattern, string, flags=0):

~\OneDrive\Documents\Python stuff\Pythonstuff\lib\re.py in _compile(pattern, flags)
    299     if not sre_compile.isstring(pattern):
    300         raise TypeError("first argument must be string or compiled pattern")
--> 301     p = sre_compile.compile(pattern, flags)
    302     if not (flags & DEBUG):
    303         if len(_cache) >= _MAXCACHE:

~\OneDrive\Documents\Python stuff\Pythonstuff\lib\sre_compile.py in compile(p, flags)
    560     if isstring(p):
    561         pattern = p
--> 562         p = sre_parse.parse(p, flags)
    563     else:
    564         pattern = None

~\OneDrive\Documents\Python stuff\Pythonstuff\lib\sre_parse.py in parse(str, flags, pattern)
    853 
    854     try:
--> 855         p = _parse_sub(source, pattern, flags & SRE_FLAG_VERBOSE, 0)
    856     except Verbose:
    857         # the VERBOSE flag was switched on inside the pattern.  to be

~\OneDrive\Documents\Python stuff\Pythonstuff\lib\sre_parse.py in _parse_sub(source, state, verbose, nested)
    414     while True:
    415         itemsappend(_parse(source, state, verbose, nested + 1,
--> 416                            not nested and not items))
    417         if not sourcematch("|"):
    418             break

~\OneDrive\Documents\Python stuff\Pythonstuff\lib\sre_parse.py in _parse(source, state, verbose, nested, first)
    614             if not item or (_len(item) == 1 and item[0][0] is AT):
    615                 raise source.error("nothing to repeat",
--> 616                                    source.tell() - here + len(this))
    617             if item[0][0] in _REPEATCODES:
    618                 raise source.error("multiple repeat",

error: nothing to repeat at position 14
```

Comment: For `result3`, you request a litteral dot `\.` after the last `|`, which can't match in your string.

Comment: I don't understand, isn't that what I have? A "\." after "|"?

Comment: result3=re.findall(r'>sp\|(\w+)\|\.\SV=\d\s([A-Z]+)', line)

Comment: Sorry, bad wording, I edited my comment. A litteral dot `\.` matches a dot and nothing else, a simple dot `.` matches anything. You shouldn't use `\.` here.

Comment: Do you mean like this? https://regex101.com/r/kOdFGu/1

Comment: Dot matches any character (except for newline characters) once. If you want to match it more than once, you'll need to add a quantifier. `.{n}` matches any character n times, while `.*` matches any number of times, and `.+` matches 1 or more times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the third pattern, you escape the `\S` which means matching a non whitespace character instead of matching `S` literally. (Is does match S itself though)

When you escape the dot `\.` it matches a dot literally, which is not present in the example data.

Reading this in the question `I essentially want python to look for a match to >sp\|(\w+)\| and continue until it finds SV=\d\s([A-Z]+). At which point, it will reset to looking for >sp\|(\w+)\|'s match.`

I think you want to match what is between the 2 patterns using a non greedy dot `.+?` to make it match at least a single character.

```
>sp\|(\w+)\|.+?SV=\d\s([A-Z]+)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZPmiRZ/1)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, and your explanation makes sense.  I'm learning python right now, and I think I was mislead to believe "\." was the nongreedy dot you explain. This explains why my code wasn't working. Thank you so much!